# SwipeRefreshLayout not working properly

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to implement a SwipeRefreshLayout in my app. The functionality of the app works fine. The SwipeRefreshLayout also works fine until the moment when it is running and the user pulls down again then what happens is the SwipeRefreshLayout goes down and start misbehaving. I noticed that the onRefresh is called once no matter how many times the user pulls down. Any suggestions on what could be going on wrong? I uploaded a youtube video of the problem [youtube_video](https://youtu.be/QfMWcBoVj8I).

This is my xml of that fragment (my app uses fragments):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
            tools:context="koemdzhiev.com.stormy.ui.HourlyForecastActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/hourly_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And this is the code in the fragment:

```
    public class Hourly_forecast_fragment extends Fragment {
    private Hour[] mHours;
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    @InjectView(R.id.hourly_swipe_refresh_layout)
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    //inject the RecyclerView as member variable
    @InjectView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mActivity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.hourly_forecast_fragment,container,false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, v);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.green,R.color.blue,R.color.orange);
        if (mRecyclerView != null)
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    //if there is internet and if the mSwipeRefreshLayout in the current and daily fragments are not already running...
                    if (mActivity.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        if (!mActivity.mCurrent_forecast_fragment.mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing() && !mActivity.mDaily_forecast_fragment.mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                            mActivity.getLocation();
                        }else{
                            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "currently refreshing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        Log.e("Forecast_fragment", "onCreateView");
        return v;
    }

    public void setUpHourlyFragment(){
        if (mActivity.mForecast != null) {
//            Toast.makeText(mActivity, getString(R.string.network_unavailable_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Hour[] hourlyForecast = mActivity.mForecast.getHourlyForecast();
            mHours = Arrays.copyOf(hourlyForecast, hourlyForecast.length, Hour[].class);

            HourAdapter adapter = new HourAdapter(mActivity, mHours);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            //if dealing with fixed size data, it is recommended to do the following...
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem using a ListView instead of RecycleView. For some reason, the SwideRefreshLayout does not work quite well with RecycleView.
**Current_fragment code:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/hourly_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```